# Convert x, y coordinates into px

Tags: php, css, coordinates

Imagine there is a post in Instagram and someone tagged in the picture and the coordinates of the tagged-person-icon in the picture is something like :

```
position: [ 
      x = 0.5162392854690552,
      y = 0.44017091393470764
  ]
```

So my **goal** is to convert this position into `px` format( by `px` I mean the `px` in the css) so I'll be able to use it the way I want it .

I believe that there is some formula to do that , but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply x by width and y by height.

```
$position = [
    'x' => 0.5162392854690552,
    'y' => 0.44017091393470764
];

$width = 800;
$height = 800;

$x = round($position['x'] * $width);
$y = round($position['y'] * $height);

$css = "position: absolute; top: {$y}px; left: {$x}px;";
echo $css;
```

gives you

```
position: absolute; top: 352px; left: 413px;
```

### Update

If the image is responsive use percentage as [@schmauch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13720553/schmauch) mentioned in the comment.

```
$x = round($position['x'] * 100);
$y = round($position['y'] * 100);

$css = "position: absolute; top: {$y}%; left: {$x}%;";
echo $css;
```

gives you

```
position: absolute; top: 44%; left: 52%;
```

Comment: If the image is responsive, you will not know it's width and height. But you could multiply x and y by 100 and use the values as percentage.

Comment: @schmauch Good point. Answer updated. TY!